# Wrap items in a grid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

im making an inventory system and iv managed to add/remove and sort the items on just the x axis. So all it does is add and remove and resort them on one line. I cant seem to figure out how to make it go down 1 y space every 10 tiles, or so. Im using a method like this for another thing in my game, but idk.. ic ant figure out how to do it for my inventory

```
                tile.x = TILE_SIZE * (i % 800);
                tile.y = TILE_SIZE * (j % 600);
```

Heres my code that adds the items to the inventory

```
    protected function addInvItem(item:MovieClip, c:Class)
    {
        item = new c();
        inventory.itemsInInventory.push(item);
        inventory.inventorySprite.addChild(item);
        item.x = (inventory.itemsInInventory.length-1)*40;
        item.y = 0;
        item.width = 30;
        item.height = 25;
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, inventory.useItem);
    }
```

This code deletes and sorts the inventory when u click on an item

```
    public function useItem(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        inventorySprite.removeChild(item);
        itemsInInventory.splice(itemsInInventory.indexOf(item), 1);
        item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem);
        sortInventory();
    }
    public function sortInventory()
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < itemsInInventory.length; i++)
        {
            itemsInInventory[i].x = i * 40;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the modular operator

```
var len:int = inventory.itemsInInventory.length;
item.x = 40 * (len%10);
item.y = 40 * Math.floor(len/10);
```

Your loop would look like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < itemsInInventory.length; i++)
{
    itemsInInventory[i].x = 40 * (i%10);
    itemsInInventory[i].y = 40 * Math.floor(i/10);
}
```

Comment: Awesome man! That almost worked, but its putting the first item in the second row on the first row and not the second, :c
it also does that for all of the following rows, puts the first item 1 row to high

Comment: Sorry. I messed up... I think it should be:
'item.y = 40 * Math.floor(len/10);'

Comment: Lol, i changed it to that before yo replied and it was putting it one space to the right on the first item and the rest were fine, but when i use the loop it works fine, so i can probably just use the loop for the add item and sort item :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: Damnit.. ok, try moving the line that pushes the item into the array to after you set the x and y.
inventory.itemsInInventory.push(item);